# Trying to add legend to a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I plot this in python:

[image]

When I go to latex an plot it, I get every label but the one that says "95% confidence interval". I tried `\addlegendentry{}` but it dit not work.

> Maybe add `\path [fill=color0, draw opacity=0, fill opacity=0.6,label=blabla]` so it recognizes the 95% curve?

[image]

```
!TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         % multilenguaje
\decimalpoint


\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,143}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{128,0,0} 
\begin{document}



\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0.75,0.75}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.501960784313725,0,0.501960784313725}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{1,0.843137254901961,0}

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2}]
\nextgroupplot[
legend cell align={left},
legend style={at={(0.5,0.3)}, anchor=north west, draw=black},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
xtick align=inside,
ytick align=inside,
x grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
xlabel={$\mathbf{x}$},
xmin=-2, xmax=10,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
ylabel={$f(\mathbf{x})$},
ymin=0.141649898838692, ymax=1.46190886017113,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\path [fill=color0, draw opacity=0, fill opacity=0.6]
(axis cs:-2,0.866792369503652)
--(axis cs:-1.54395439543954,0.919530186350506)
--(axis cs:-1.54515451545155,0.919558548611325)
--(axis cs:-1.54635463546355,0.919586912138129)
--(axis cs:-1.54755475547555,0.919615276934969)
--(axis cs:-1.54875487548755,0.919643643002155)
--(axis cs:-1.54995499549955,0.919672010335886)
--(axis cs:-1.55115511551155,0.91970037894041)
--(axis cs:-1.55235523552355,0.919728748808043)
--(axis cs:-1.55355535553555,0.919757119944978)
--(axis cs:-1.55475547554755,0.919785492353284)
--(axis cs:-1.55595559555956,0.919813866025442)
--(axis cs:-1.55715571557156,0.919842240965596)
--(axis cs:-1.55835583558356,0.919870617173895)
--(axis cs:-1.55955595559556,0.919898994648742)
--(axis cs:-1.56075607560756,0.919927373388266)
--(axis cs:-1.56195619561956,0.919955753398611)
--(axis cs:-1.56315631563156,0.91998413467223)
--(axis cs:-1.56435643564356,0.920012517217042)
--(axis cs:-1.56555655565557,0.920040901027542)
--(axis cs:-1.56675667566757,0.920069286103877)
--(axis cs:-1.56795679567957,0.920097672444508)
--(axis cs:-1.56915691569157,0.920126060053246)
--(axis cs:-1.57035703570357,0.920154448926605)
--(axis cs:-1.57155715571557,0.920182839066768)
--(axis cs:-1.57275727572757,0.920211230472008)
--(axis cs:-1.57395739573957,0.920239623144404)
--(axis cs:-1.57515751575158,0.920268017082363)
--(axis cs:-1.57635763576358,0.920296412282115)
--(axis cs:-1.57755775577558,0.920324808753618)
--(axis cs:-1.57875787578758,0.920353206485544)
--(axis cs:-1.57995799579958,0.920381605483879)
--(axis cs:-1.58115811581158,0.920410005744882)
--(axis cs:-1.58235823582358,0.920438407272788)
--(axis cs:-1.58355835583558,0.920466810065772)
--(axis cs:-1.58475847584758,0.920495214122185)
--(axis cs:-1.58595859585959,0.920523619444161)
--(axis cs:-1.58715871587159,0.92055202602805)
--(axis cs:-1.58835883588359,0.920580433878065)
--(axis cs:-1.58955895589559,0.920608842992342)
--(axis cs:-1.59075907590759,0.920637253369196)
--(axis cs:-1.59195919591959,0.920665665008923)
--(axis cs:-1.59315931593159,0.920694077915495)
--(axis cs:-1.59435943594359,0.92072249208154)
--(axis cs:-1.5955595559556,0.920750907511129)
--(axis cs:-1.5967596759676,0.92077932420829)
--(axis cs:-1.5979597959796,0.920807742165403)
--(axis cs:-1.5991599159916,0.920836161386821)
--(axis cs:-1.6003600360036,0.920864581868738)
--(axis cs:-1.6015601560156,0.920893003615276)
--(axis cs:-1.6027602760276,0.920921426622798)
--(axis cs:-1.6039603960396,0.920949850895393)
--(axis cs:-1.60516051605161,0.92097827642937)
--(axis cs:-1.60636063606361,0.921006703223108)
--(axis cs:-1.60756075607561,0.921035131280686)
--(axis cs:-1.60876087608761,0.921063560602238)
--(axis cs:-1.60996099609961,0.92109199118225)
--(axis cs:-1.61116111611161,0.921120423026795)
--(axis cs:-1.61236123612361,0.921148856130204)
--(axis cs:-1.61356135613561,0.92117729049283)
--(axis cs:-1.61476147614761,0.92120572612059)
--(axis cs:-1.61596159615962,0.921234163009839)
--(axis cs:-1.61716171617162,0.921262601158891)
--(axis cs:-1.61836183618362,0.921291040569876)
--(axis cs:-1.61956195619562,0.921319481241166)
--(axis cs:-1.62076207620762,0.921347923171066)
--(axis cs:-1.62196219621962,0.921376366363514)
--(axis cs:-1.62316231623162,0.921404810813083)
--(axis cs:-1.62436243624362,0.921433256527688)
--(axis cs:-1.62556255625563,0.921461703501694)
--(axis cs:-1.62676267626763,0.921490151735422)
--(axis cs:-1.62796279627963,0.921518601225234)
--(axis cs:-1.62916291629163,0.92154705197703)
--(axis cs:-1.63036303630363,0.921575503989253)
--(axis cs:-1.63156315631563,0.921603957260118)
--(axis cs:-1.63276327632763,0.92163241179175)
--(axis cs:-1.63396339633963,0.921660867580591)
--(axis cs:-1.63516351635164,0.921689324628724)
--(axis cs:-1.63636363636364,0.921717782938365)
--(axis cs:-1.63756375637564,0.921746242503935)
--(axis cs:-1.63876387638764,0.921774703329466)
--(axis cs:-1.63996399639964,0.921803165413383)
--(axis cs:-1.64116411641164,0.921831628755713)
--(axis cs:-1.64236423642364,0.92186009335687)
--(axis cs:-1.64356435643564,0.921888559215109)
--(axis cs:-1.64476447644764,0.921917026332473)
--(axis cs:-1.64596459645965,0.921945494707352)
--(axis cs:-1.64716471647165,0.921973964339977)
--(axis cs:-1.64836483648365,0.922002435228662)
--(axis cs:-1.64956495649565,0.922030907377359)
--(axis cs:-1.65076507650765,0.922059380778831)
--(axis cs:-1.65196519651965,0.922087855444605)
--(axis cs:-1.65316531653165,0.922116331361625)
--(axis cs:-1.65436543654365,0.922144808539502)
--(axis cs:-1.65556555655566,0.922173286972881)
--(axis cs:-1.65676567656766,0.922201766663922)
--(axis cs:-1.65796579657966,0.922230247608921)
--(axis cs:-1.65916591659166,0.922258729811977)
--(axis cs:-1.66036603660366,0.922287213271364)
--(axis cs:-1.66156615661566,0.922315697989231)
--(axis cs:-1.66276627662766,0.922344183960127)
--(axis cs:-1.66396639663966,0.922372671188031)
--(axis cs:-1.66516651665167,0.922401159673226)
--(axis cs:-1.66636663666367,0.922429649413967)
--(axis cs:-1.66756675667567,0.922458140408538)
--(axis cs:-1.66876687668767,0.922486632659142)
--(axis cs:-1.66996699669967,0.922515126166)
--(axis cs:-1.67116711671167,0.922543620925533)
--(axis cs:-1.67236723672367,0.922572116941714)
--(axis cs:-1.67356735673567,0.922600614212821)
--(axis cs:-1.67476747674767,0.922629112739226)
--(axis cs:-1.67596759675968,0.922657612521065)
--(axis cs:-1.67716771677168,0.922686113556656)
--(axis cs:-1.67836783678368,0.922714615844408)
--(axis cs:-1.67956795679568,0.922743119388172)
--(axis cs:-1.68076807680768,0.922771624190134)
--(axis cs:-1.68196819681968,0.92280013024115)
--(axis cs:-1.68316831683168,0.922828637546953)
--(axis cs:-1.68436843684368,0.922857146107929)
--(axis cs:-1.68556855685569,0.922885655920371)
--(axis cs:-1.68676867686769,0.922914166988332)
--(axis cs:-1.68796879687969,0.922942679310205)
--(axis cs:-1.68916891689169,0.922971192884237)
--(axis cs:-1.69036903690369,0.9229997077126)
--(axis cs:-1.69156915691569,0.923028223791677)
--(axis cs:-1.69276927692769,0.923056741125537)
--(axis cs:-1.69396939693969,0.923085259712432)
--(axis cs:-1.6951695169517,0.923113779550806)
--(axis cs:-1.6963696369637,0.923142300640763)
--(axis cs:-1.6975697569757,0.92317082298445)
--(axis cs:-1.6987698769877,0.923199346583944)
--(axis cs:-1.6999699969997,0.923227871430156)
--(axis cs:-1.7011701170117,0.923256397528899)
--(axis cs:-1.7023702370237,0.923284924882128)
--(axis cs:-1.99279927992799,0.930225049939748)
--(axis cs:-1.99399939993999,0.930253877748194)
--(axis cs:-1.995199519952,0.93028270677811)
--(axis cs:-1.996399639964,0.930311537026441)
--(axis cs:-1.997599759976,0.93034036849834)
--(axis cs:-1.998799879988,0.930369201189014)
--(axis cs:-2,0.93039803510041)
--cycle;
\addlegendentry{$f(\mathbf{x})$}
\addplot [very thick, myblue]
table {%
-2 0.201661669808349
-1.998799879988 0.201857010241904
-1.997599759976 0.202052610231707
-1.996399639964 0.202248470186105
-1.995199519952 0.202444590514115
-1.99399939993999 0.202640971625421
-1.99279927992799 0.20283761393038
-1.99159915991599 0.203034517840017
-1.99039903990399 0.20323168376603
-1.98919891989199 0.203429112120788
-1.98799879987999 0.203626803317334
-1.98679867986799 0.203824757769386
-1.98559855985599 0.204022975891336
-1.98439843984398 0.204221458098251
-1.98319831983198 0.204420204805877
-1.98199819981998 0.204619216430635
-1.98079807980798 0.204818493389626
-1.97959795979598 0.20501803610063
-1.97839783978398 0.205217844982106
-1.97719771977198 0.205417920453195
-1.97599759975998 0.20561826293372
-1.97479747974797 0.205818872844185
-1.97359735973597 0.20601975060578
-1.97239723972397 0.206220896640376
-1.97119711971197 0.206422311370533
-1.96999699969997 0.206623995219493
-1.96879687968797 0.206825948611187
-1.96759675967597 0.207028171970234
-1.96639663966397 0.207230665721941
-1.96519651965197 0.207433430292303
-1.96399639963996 0.207636466108007
-1.96279627962796 0.20783977359643
-1.96159615961596 0.208043353185642
-1.96039603960396 0.208247205304404
-1.95919591959196 0.208451330382171
-1.95799579957996 0.208655728849093
-1.95679567956796 0.208860401136015
-1.95559555955596 0.209065347674477
-1.95439543954395 0.209270568896716
-1.95319531953195 0.209476065235668
-1.95199519951995 0.209681837124966
-1.95079507950795 0.209887884998943
-1.94959495949595 0.210094209292632
-1.94839483948395 0.210300810441766
-1.94719471947195 0.210507688882781
-1.94599459945995 0.210714845052814
-1.94479447944794 0.210922279389708
-1.94359435943594 0.211129992332006
-1.94239423942394 0.21133798431896
-1.94119411941194 0.211546255790526
-1.93999399939994 0.211754807187366
-1.93879387938794 0.211963638950851
-1.93759375937594 0.212172751523059
-1.93639363936394 0.212382145346776
-1.93519351935194 0.2125918208655
-1.93399339933993 0.212801778523439
-1.93279327932793 0.213012018765511
-1.93159315931593 0.213222542037347
-1.93039303930393 0.213433348785292
-1.92919291929193 0.213644439456404
-1.92799279927993 0.213855814498454
-1.92679267926793 0.214067474359931
-1.92559255925593 0.214279419490039
-1.65796579657966 0.89344797874546
-1.65676567656766 0.893429877850131
-1.65556555655566 0.893411776675203
-1.65436543654365 0.8933936752207
-1.65316531653165 0.893375573486665
-1.65196519651965 0.893357471473129
-1.65076507650765 0.893339369180134
-1.64956495649565 0.893321266607708
-1.64836483648365 0.893303163755883
-1.64716471647165 0.893285060624704
-1.64596459645965 0.8932669572142
-1.64476447644764 0.893248853524408
-1.64356435643564 0.893230749555362
-1.64236423642364 0.893212645307104
-1.64116411641164 0.893194540779664
-1.63996399639964 0.893176435973068
-1.63876387638764 0.89315833088737
-1.63756375637564 0.89314022552259
-1.63636363636364 0.893122119878772
-1.63516351635164 0.893104013955948
-1.63396339633963 0.89308590775415
-1.63276327632763 0.893067801273421
-1.63156315631563 0.893049694513792
-1.63036303630363 0.893031587475295
-1.62916291629163 0.893013480157977
-1.62796279627963 0.892995372561856
-1.62676267626763 0.89297726468698
-1.62556255625563 0.892959156533381
-1.62436243624362 0.892941048101095
-1.62316231623162 0.892922939390155
-1.62196219621962 0.892904830400596
-1.62076207620762 0.892886721132456
-1.61956195619562 0.89286861158577
-1.61836183618362 0.892850501760577
-1.61716171617162 0.892832391656903
-1.61596159615962 0.892814281274786
-1.61476147614761 0.89279617061427
-1.61356135613561 0.892778059675382
-1.61236123612361 0.89275994845816
-1.61116111611161 0.892741836962635
-1.60996099609961 0.892723725188851
-1.60876087608761 0.892705613136836
0.352235223522352 0.862765773532674
0.353435343534354 0.862747256697451
0.354635463546355 0.862728739647085
0.355835583558356 0.862710222381603
0.357035703570357 0.862691704901058
0.358235823582358 0.86267318720548
0.359435943594359 0.862654669294919
0.360636063606361 0.862636151169424
0.361836183618362 0.862617632829018
0.363036303630363 0.862599114273761
0.364236423642364 0.862580595503683
0.365436543654366 0.862562076518831
0.366636663666367 0.862543557319245
0.367836783678368 0.862525037904971
0.369036903690369 0.862506518276044
0.37023702370237 0.862487998432511
0.371437143714372 0.862469478374414
0.372637263726373 0.862450958101794
0.373837383738374 0.862432437614691
0.375037503750375 0.862413916913148
0.376237623762377 0.862395395997207
0.377437743774378 0.862376874866916
0.378637863786379 0.862358353522303
0.37983798379838 0.862339831963421
0.381038103810381 0.86232131019031
0.382238223822382 0.86230278820301
0.383438343834384 0.862284266001564
0.384638463846385 0.862265743586015
0.385838583858386 0.862247220956401
0.387038703870387 0.862228698112771
0.388238823882388 0.862210175055166
0.389438943894389 0.862191651783613
0.390639063906391 0.86217312829817
0.391839183918392 0.862154604598879
0.393039303930393 0.862136080685774
0.394239423942394 0.862117556558909
0.395439543954396 0.862099032218308
0.396639663966397 0.862080507664025
0.397839783978398 0.862061982896101
0.399039903990399 0.862043457914575
0.4002400240024 0.862024932719492
0.401440144014402 0.862006407310892
0.402640264026403 0.861987881688819
0.403840384038404 0.861969355853311
0.405040504050405 0.861950829804415
0.406240624062407 0.861932303542172
0.407440744074408 0.861913777066622
0.408640864086409 0.861895250377808
0.40984098409841 0.861876723475768
0.411041104110411 0.861858196360552
0.412241224122412 0.861839669032198
0.413441344134414 0.861821141490745
0.414641464146415 0.861802613736239
0.415841584158416 0.861784085768725
0.417041704170417 0.861765557588237
0.418241824182418 0.861747029194823

};
\addlegendentry{$a_{EI}$}
\addplot [thick, black, mark=triangle*, mark size=3, mark options={solid,fill=green,draw=black}, only marks]
table {%
-2 0.898595202302031
};
\addlegendentry{Siguiente mejor estimación}
\end{groupplot}

\node at ({$(current bounding box.south west)!0.5!(current bounding box.south east)$}|-{$(current bounding box.south west)!0.98!(current bounding box.north west)$})[
  scale=0.6,
  anchor=north,
  text=black,
  rotate=0.0
]{};
%Proceso gaussiano y función de adquisicióndespués de 2 pasos
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example throws an error, if you can, fix it so it doesn't.

Comment: I had to cut the number of rows because it exceeded 30k

Comment: DId you cut away an `\addplot table {` as well? Probably you can remove all the data points except a couple in each plot, but don't remove the plotting commands.

Comment: let me fix it. Thx

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Try now. It should be working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `\path` isn't added to the legend. You can use

```
\addlegendimage{fill=color0, draw opacity=0, fill opacity=0.6,area legend}
```

to add a new "dummy plot" in the legend.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=0.98\textwidth}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}         % multilenguaje
\decimalpoint


\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,0,143}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{128,0,0} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0.75,0.75}
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0.12156862745098,0.466666666666667,0.705882352941177}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.501960784313725,0,0.501960784313725}
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{1,0.843137254901961,0}

\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2}]
\nextgroupplot[
legend cell align={left},
legend style={at={(0.5,0.3)}, anchor=north west, draw=black},
tick align=outside,
tick pos=left,
xtick align=inside,
ytick align=inside,
x grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
xlabel={$\mathbf{x}$},
xmin=-2, xmax=10,
xtick style={color=black},
y grid style={white!69.01960784313725!black},
ylabel={$f(\mathbf{x})$},
ymin=0.141649898838692, ymax=1.46190886017113,
ytick style={color=black}
]
\path [fill=color0, draw opacity=0, fill opacity=0.6]
(axis cs:-2,0.866792369503652)
--(axis cs:-1.54395439543954,0.919530186350506)
--(axis cs:-2,0.93039803510041)
--cycle;

\addlegendentry{$f(\mathbf{x})$}
\addplot [very thick, myblue]
table {%
-2 0.201661669808349
-1.998799879988 0.201857010241904
-1.997599759976 0.202052610231707
};
\addlegendentry{$a_{EI}$}
\addplot [thick, black, mark=triangle*, mark size=3, mark options={solid,fill=green,draw=black}, only marks]
table {%
-2 0.898595202302031
};

% add this
\addlegendimage{fill=color0, draw opacity=0, fill opacity=0.6,area legend}

\addlegendentry{Siguiente mejor estimación}
\end{groupplot}

\node at ({$(current bounding box.south west)!0.5!(current bounding box.south east)$}|-{$(current bounding box.south west)!0.98!(current bounding box.north west)$})[
  scale=0.6,
  anchor=north,
  text=black,
  rotate=0.0
]{};
%Proceso gaussiano y función de adquisicióndespués de 2 pasos
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I want `\addlegendimage{fill=gauss, draw opacity=0, fill opacity=0.6,area legend}` to appear in the above plot instead of the one below.

Comment: @NaveganTeX  Move it up above the previous `\addplot`. The order of the "images" in the legend is determined by the order of the `\addplot`s/`\addlegendimage`, the order of the texts in the legend is determined by the order of `\addlegendentry`s.

Comment: Is there any way to make the boxes to look more "rectangular / flat"?

Comment: @NaveganTeX Yes, by modifying the `area legend` style. See the manual or for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431597/

Comment: I was referring myself to the actual boxes not the ones with the legends.

Comment: @NaveganTeX Now I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: The two boxes with the curves have a square shape. I want them to have a rectangular shape, intestead

Comment: @NaveganTeX Oh, you mean the axes. `width=10cm,height=5cm`, or whatever length you want, add to the options of the `groupplot` environment (but *not* inside the `group style`).